# Sql запрос с параметрами в цикле для добавления данных в базу

Tags: c#, sql

Сделал такую конструкцию, для добавления данных в базу, вопрос, Правильно ли написан запрос, и если учитывать то, что это цикл, будет ли эффективным такое решение?

```
using (SqlConnection connection =new SqlConnection(connextionstring))
        {
            SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class1", connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class2", connection);
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand command3 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class3", connection);
            command3.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand command4 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class4", connection);
            command4.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlCommand command5 = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class5", connection);
            command5.ExecuteNonQuery();

             Class1 contactMary = ObjectSpace.FindObject<Class1>();

            foreach (var VARIABLE in mass2)
            {
            String[] words = VARIABLE.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var a= contactMary.METHODID = Convert.ToInt16(words[0]);
            var b= contactMary.DESCRIPTION = words[1];
            var c= contactMary.METHODTYPEID = words[2];
            var d= contactMary.TEXTDESCRIPTION = words[3];
            SqlCommand command6 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Class1 (METHODID, DESCRIPTION, METHODTYPEID, TEXTDESCRIPTION) VALUES (@a, @b, @c, @d)", connection);
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",a);
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b",b);
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",c);
            command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d",d);

            command6.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

Comment: Наверное потому что вы пишете невалидный C# код, вам компилятор ничего не подсказывает?

Comment: [Параметризация запросов](https://metanit.com/sharp/adonet/2.9.php) ?

Comment: Вот то есть Вы полагаете, что добрый C# возьмёт и догадается, что во фрагменте `... SET METHODID="a", DESCRI...` он вместо `a` должен подставить значение переменной, да ещё правильно её обрамить кавычками? А ещё догадается, что во фрагменте `... INTO Class1 SET ...` этого делать не надо... Огорчу - Вам придётся сделать это самостоятельно.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо за ответ, да он как раз и показывает невалидность.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ, я по логике понимаю что  где a,b,c туда вставляются переменные. Но с параметризованными запросами не сталкивался еще.

Comment: Как успехи? Если не получается - спрашивайте (можете отредактировать этот вопрос). Если получилось - покажите свой код. Я почему интересуюсь: в показанном коде нет освобождения ресурсов; и создание SqlCommand следовало бы вынести из цикла. В общем, так и тянет отрефакторить...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо за ответ и интерес, я подправил вопрос вот такой код у меня получился. Освобождение ресурсов есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, всем переменным нужно давать говорящие имена. `command2`, `command3` - глядя на их имена, что можно предположить о них? Что делают эти команды? Непонятно...

Можно назвать, например, так: `deleteClass2Command`, `deleteClass3Command` - при этом сразу ясно, для чего они предназначены.

Имена таблиц в базе данных, кстати, тоже хорошо бы переименовать. Потому как `Class1` мало о чём говорит.

---

Освобождать (диспозить) нужно не только соединение, но и все команды. Т. е. их тоже нужно обернуть в `using`.

```
using (var deleteClass2Command = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class1", connection))
{ .... }
```

---

Идём дальше. В принципе, вовсе необязательно использовать несколько команд. Достаточно одной переопределять запрос.

```
connection.Open();
using (var deleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Class1", connection))
{
    deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Class2";
    deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    deleteCommand.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Class3";
    deleteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // и т. д.
}
```

Тут имя команды является общим для всех, поэтому оно без уточнения, к какой таблице относится.

---

Далее. Название переменной `contactMary` - хорошее. И регистр правильно набран, в соответствии с [гайдами](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/naming-guidelines). Правда, совершенно неясно, зачем оно нужно.

А вот `mass2` - плохо. Вероятно это *массив* (по-английски *array*). Массив *чего*? Что в нём содержится, какие объекты?

`VARIABLE` - совсем плохо. Слово *variable* означает *переменная* и только. И оно не должно быть большими буквами.

Использование метода `AddWithValue` может привести к проблемам с производительностью. Советую ознакомиться: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Лучше явно указывать типы данных в колонках. Укажите именно те значения перечисления `SqlDbType`, которые в таблице БД.

```
using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Class1 (METHODID, DESCRIPTION, METHODTYPEID, TEXTDESCRIPTION) " +
        "VALUES (@id, @desc, @typeId, @textDesc)",
        connection))
{
    foreach (var item in someCollection)
    {
        String[] words = item.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var id = Convert.ToInt16(words[0]);
        var desc = words[1];
        var typeId = words[2];
        var textDesc = words[3];

        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = id;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@desc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = desc;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@typeId", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = typeId;
        insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@textDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textDesc;

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Создание команды я вынес из цикла: незачем на каждой итерации её пересоздавать.
Опять же, изменил имена параметров. Тут можно упрекнуть меня в том, что они слишком короткие, малоговорящие... Ну дык, разглагольствовать мы все горазды, а набивать длинный код неохота... :)

---

И напоследок, нужно добавить обработку исключений и проверку возвращаемых значений метода `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: Александр, спасибо за развернутый ответ, он мне очень помог, на счет имен и прочего, читаю чистый код, и ловлю себя на мысли, что в моем случае он совсем не чистый, но я заложник метода, типа сделай сначала топорно, чтобы работало, затем улучшай, убирай лишнее модернизируй. Может я не прав.