# При нажатии на кнопку "Обновить" ошибка System.ArgumentException:

Tags: c#, sql-server

Пишу небольшое приложение. При нажатии на кнопку "Изменить" выдает ошибку:

> System.ArgumentException: "Отсутствует сопоставление типа объекта System.Windows.Forms.TextBox с известным собственным типом управляемого поставщика."

```
private  async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Обработчик кнопки "Изменить" во вкладке "UPDATE"  используем метод "async"//
        {
            if (label8.Visible)         
                label8.Visible = false; 


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox3.Text) &&  // проверка поля "textBox3" если  оно  пустое  то переходим ниже к " ELSE" //
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text) &&    // проверка поля "textBox4" если  оно  пустое то переходим ниже к  "ELSE" //
               !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox5.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox5.Text))      // проверка поля "textBox5" если  оно  пустое то переходим ниже к  "ELSE" //

            {                                                                                             
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [Products] SET [Name]=@Name, [Price]=@Price WHERE [Id]=@Id", sqlConnection);  // Эта строка выполняет команду обновления информации о продуктах //

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id" , textBox5);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox4);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Price", textBox3);

               await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();                         // здесь ошибка в этой строке  //
            }  
            
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox4.Text))
            {
                label8.Visible = true;
                label8.Text = "ID должен быть заполнен!";
            }
            else
            {
                label8.Visible = true;
                label8.Text = "Поля 'Имя' и 'Цена' должны быть заполнены!";
            }
         }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Name`, это что? Наверно текстовое значение, верно? Так почему вы туда пихаете объект `TextBox`, со своими свойствами по типу "размер", "цвет", "шрифт" и тд.? Подумайте просто логически, что тут вы делаете не так `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Name", textBox4);`...

Comment: Addwithvalue  метод внутри нужно написать textbox.value ,?

Comment: Мыслите в нужном направление, только у `TextBox` есть `value`? На сколько я знаю там `.Text`.

Comment: Не используйте метод `AddWithValue`, он плохой, забудьте про него. Причины: [1](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) - достаточно прочесть любую из статей. Используйте взамен метод `Add`.

Comment: Всегда давайте нормальные говорящее имена всем переменным. `button2`, `textBox4`, `label8` - что это такое? Как по этим названиям понять, для чего они предназначены? Посмотрите, например, [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/960667/184217) моё ревью кода. И там пример использования метода `Add`.

Comment: Большое спасибо за подсказку. Да глупая ошибка по невнимательности. Спасибо всем кто откликнулся. Исправил все заработало. button2, textBox4, label8 - и эти значения нужно более понятно называть согласен с Вами. Единственно в оправдание скажу что там этих компонентов мало.